# Synchronized stored procedure execution in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, synchronization, locking, boost-interprocess

I have a stored procedure in *mysql* thats to perform a task that needs to be synchronized such that if two application calls the stored procedure, only one can access a section of code to perform the task, keeping the other one to get blocked until the first one finishes the task.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GEN_ID(IN NAME VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN 
  DECLARE maxLen int default 0;
START TRANSACTION;
   #the section of code that needs to be synchronized
COMMIT
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

So, if two applications call the stored procedure simultaneously, the task has to be synchronized.

a. But *Start TRANSACTION* and *COMMIT* did NOT synchronize the execution.

b. And LOCK TABLES *tableA* can not be used in stored procedure to ensure the synchronization too.

c. I tried to synchronize the stored procedure call in application level. I used

> boost_interprocess scoped_lock lock();

It worked perfectly fine in boost 1.41

But interprocess locking mutex is not supported in the boost 1.34 library, which is what is available in my case.

Is there a way to synchronize the stored procedure section of code such that when two calls are made simultaneously, one gets blocked before the other gets executed?

(added the following) 
edited code: to give an idea what I am trying to perform in the synchronized block of the stored procedure.

It gets the last assigned id, and increment it by one and check whether it is not used for someother 'name' record. 
When a valid id is found, update the last assigned id record table and then associate that with the 'name' given.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GEN_ID(IN NAME VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN 
  DECLARE maxLen int default 0;
START TRANSACTION;
   #the section of code that needs to be synchronized
    SELECT lastid into lastgenerated FROM DB_last_id WHERE key = 'NAME_ID';    
findid_loop:
    LOOP
    set lastid = lastid + 1;
    #this is to check whether it was assigned with someother name before.
    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_name_id WHERE name_id = lastgenerated) then
                     set nameid = lastgenerated;
                     set found = true;
                     LEAVE findid_loop;
            END IF;

            #for loop limit check
            IF (counter < loopLimit) then
                    set counter = counter + 1;
                    ITERATE findid_loop;
            ELSE
                    #reached the limit and not found.
                    LEAVE findid_loop;
            END IF;
    END LOOP findid_loop;

     #if a valid id, update last id and assign to name.
     IF (found) THEN
            #update the id.
            update DB_last_id  set lastid = nameid where key = 'NAME_ID';
            insert into user_name_id values (nameid ,name);
     ELSE
            #return an empty string for the application to take action on the failure.
            set nameid = '';
    END IF;
#end transaction here.
COMMIT

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What storage engine do your tables use?  They must be InnoDB for transactions/locking to work.

Comment: The storage engine is InnoDB for the tables. But still it does not seem to be working. To verify this, I did a sleep (15), to wait for 15secs right after START TRANSACTION. When I made simultaneous calls to the stored procedure, both seem to come out after 15 seconds. If START TRANSACTION ensures the synchronization, then the second call to the stored procedure should get over after 30secs or so. right? (15secs for the first call to get over, then the second one goes inside the START TRANSACTION and sleeps for 15secs)

Comment: What exactly is the code you're trying to synchronise?  If you simply want SQL operations to be atomic, performing them in a transaction should accomplish that.  If you're affecting other state, like system variables, you'll need to obtain a lock on a table/record dedicated to this purpose.  And the lack of a delay in your second call is not *necessarily* indicative of the lock failing (there could, for example, be cacheing issues that make the second call run faster than the first; or the second call could take a different execution path to the first).  Please provide the full code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting a transaction with START TRANSACTION does not actually start it. The first table access following START TRANSACTION does. Opening a transaction isn't also a mean for concurrency control. If you need just that, you can rely on the advisory locks system MySQL provides through `GET_LOCK()`, `RELEASE_LOCK()`, and a few other related functions.

An alternative way to implement concurrency control, through transactions this time, would be by relying on exclusive row locks. Since `SELECT` statements are non-locking in InnoDB, issuing such query starts a transaction, however it neither sets any locks nor respects any pre-existing ones. To have a `SELECT` statement actually block if there is an earlier transaction operating on the same information (row), you have to use `FOR UPDATE` clause. For example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT lastid into lastgenerated FROM DB_last_id WHERE key = 'NAME_ID' FOR UPDATE;
...
```

With this construction there will never be two concurrent transactions operating on the same `'NAME_ID'` past the `SELECT` statement that was explicitly told to perform a locking read.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in my comments above, you *should* find that a transaction is sufficient for most needs; however, if you need to explicitly wait until the other call has completed, use [`GET_LOCK(str,timeout)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock):

> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string ***`str`***, using a timeout of ***`timeout`*** seconds. Returns `1` if the lock was obtained successfully, `0` if the attempt timed out (for example, because another client has previously locked the name), or `NULL` if an error occurred (such as running out of memory or the thread was killed with [*`mysqladmin kill`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqladmin.html)). If you have a lock obtained with [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock), it is released when you execute [`RELEASE_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock), execute a new [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock), or your connection terminates (either normally or abnormally). Locks obtained with [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) do not interact with transactions. That is, committing a transaction does not release any such locks obtained during the transaction.
>
> This function can be used to implement application locks or to simulate record locks. Names are locked on a server-wide basis. If a name has been locked by one client, [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) blocks any request by another client for a lock with the same name. This enables clients that agree on a given lock name to use the name to perform cooperative advisory locking. But be aware that it also enables a client that is not among the set of cooperating clients to lock a name, either inadvertently or deliberately, and thus prevent any of the cooperating clients from locking that name. One way to reduce the likelihood of this is to use lock names that are database-specific or application-specific. For example, use lock names of the form ***`db_name.str`*** or ***`app_name.str`***.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1',10);
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('lock2');
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock2',10);
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('lock2');
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('lock1');
>         -> NULL
> ```
>
> The second [`RELEASE_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock) call returns `NULL` because the lock `'lock1'` was automatically released by the second [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) call.
>
> If multiple clients are waiting for a lock, the order in which they will acquire it is undefined and depends on factors such as the thread library in use. In particular, applications should not assume that clients will acquire the lock in the same order that they issued the lock requests.
>
> > **Note**
> >     Before MySQL 5.5.3, if a client attempts to acquire a lock that is already held by another client, it blocks according to the ***`timeout`*** argument. If the blocked client terminates, its thread does not die until the lock request times out.
>
> This function is unsafe for statement-based replication. Beginning with MySQL 5.5.1, a warning is logged if you use this function when [`binlog_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) is set to `STATEMENT`. (Bug #47995)

Comment: I read about GET_LOCK from mysql documents. Then I tried to test it by executing the                                                      mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock2',10);
   -> 1  twice in the same session and assumed that the second call to GET_LOCK with the same name (lock2) dint wait for the first one to finish. I tested this in my stored procedure just now by calling the stored procedure from two different sessions. It worked perfectly fine. The second call to GET_LOCK waited for the first one to release before it timed out. Thanks, eggyal!

Comment: though both your solution and Mushu's solve my case, I could only pick one answer for this question topic. I picked his one as that was simpler and more appropriate for my case.

Comment: sorry I still could not 'upvote', because I dont have enough points to do so. I will come back here when I get enough points. Thanks!

Comment: Update for Mysql 7.5.  GET_LOCK will no longer release previous locks, and you can hold multiple locks.