# Executing one MySql Stored procedure at simultaneous hit

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have developed an web application, reservation kind of thing.

When 2 users hit simultaneously, the query/Stored procedure is getting executed.

I want to restrict one execution at a time.

I went through this link "[Synchronized stored procedure execution in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561535/synchronized-stored-procedure-execution-in-mysql)".

My problem is similar, but I am unable to understand.

Please help me, how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Please use that link that you have mentioned in your question its worth. Try to understand it.. as its all in simple language